# bootstrap slider after convert to wordpress .. image and slider size

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am converting bootstrap slider into wordpress . 
the original html work look fin

http://t4uacademy.com/univ/

site 
http://www.univchiropractic.com/

but its actually because images a perfectly cut and sized . 
to 1920 by 500

I already used `add_image_size( 'slider', 1920, 500 );`

in WordPress I have the following problems

1- images are not all 1920 by 500 some are like 1920 by 1080 so that create a gap so after change the size.

2- some images like square 2000*4000 this result a bigger gap

3- small images and not resized to be bigger even I used `add_image_size( 'slider', 1920, 500 );` its only resize to smaller .

4- I try to add CSS to stretch the images but first 2 points looks really bad . thats why I deleted it

Answer (score 0):

did you try adding "true" `add_image_size( 'slider', 1920, 500 , true  );`
this will hard cut the image .

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/ for more info

Comment: about resize to bigger its have no good doing in css as you are doing now

Comment: after hard cut the css stretch will not be so bad idea

Comment: I think there is no thing we can do more .